# ZeroMQ не отправляет сообщения

Tags: c++, zeromq

Подскажите по библиотеке Zmq(Она же 0mq, и она же Zeromq)

Использую код из примера:

```
void *context = zmq_init (1);
void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://192.168.5.241:5551");
zmq_msg_t reply;
zmq_msg_init_size (&reply, 5);
memcpy (zmq_msg_data (&reply), "World", 5);
zmq_send (responder, &reply, 0);
zmq_msg_close (&reply);
zmq_close (responder);
zmq_term (context);
```

сервер приёмник сообщения не получает, прошу принять во внимание то что он настроен корректно и в нём самом проблем быть не должно.

Comment: а мы должны поверить, что оно все правильно настроенно и работает?

Comment: сервер проверен другим софтом использующим zeromq

Comment: ок, допустим оно там работает. У Вас есть гарантия, что там такой же порт/айпи, и такой же тип сокета?

Comment: 100% ная гарантия

Comment: на сервере я так понимаю `ZMQ_REP` ? тогда на клиенте нужно `ZMQ_REQ`.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: меня терзают смутные сомнения, что там ещё много чего нужно поменять:)